# Python store output as a variable after running an executable command

Tags: python, output, executable

"TMalign..." is an executable file that I used to get data. How could I store the output into a variable so that I could extract target values from the output. The executable file is compiled from a long .cpp, so I do not think I could call the variable names from there.

```
import sys,os
os.system("./TMalign 3w4u.pdb 6bb5.pdb -u 139") #some command I have
```

The output is like, and I need to extract the **TM-score values**:

```
*********************************************************************
 * TM-align (Version 20190822): protein structure alignment          *
 * References: Y Zhang, J Skolnick. Nucl Acids Res 33, 2302-9 (2005) *
 * Please email comments and suggestions to yangzhanglab@umich.edu   *
 *********************************************************************

Name of Chain_1: 3w4u.pdb (to be superimposed onto Chain_2)
Name of Chain_2: 6bb5.pdb
Length of Chain_1: 141 residues
Length of Chain_2: 139 residues

Aligned length= 139, RMSD=   1.07, Seq_ID=n_identical/n_aligned= 0.590
TM-score= 0.94726 (if normalized by length of Chain_1, i.e., LN=141, d0=4.42)
TM-score= 0.96044 (if normalized by length of Chain_2, i.e., LN=139, d0=4.38)
TM-score= 0.96044 (if normalized by user-specified LN=139.00 and d0=4.38)
(You should use TM-score normalized by length of the reference structure)

(":" denotes residue pairs of d <  5.0 Angstrom, "." denotes other aligned residues)
SLTKTERTIIVSMWAKISTQADTIGTETLERLFLSHPQTKTYFPHFDLHPGSAQLRAHGSKVVAAVGDAVKSIDDIGGALSKLSELHAYILRVDPVNFKLLSHCLLVTLAARFPADFTAEAHAAWDKFLSVVSSVLTEKYR
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. .
-LSPADKTNVKAAWGKVGAHAGEYGAEALERMFLSFPTTKTYFPHFDLSHGSAQVKGHGKKVADALTNAVAHVDDMPNALSALSDLHAHKLRVDPVNFKLLSHCLLVTLAAHLPAEFTPAVHASLDKFLASVSTVLTSK-Y

Total CPU time is  0.03 seconds
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried the solution below?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, except for the for loop line. It should be '\n' in the parenthesis. But still big thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look toward the following approach:

```
import re
from subprocess import check_output

ret = check_output(['./TMalign', '3w4u.pdb', '6bb5.pdb', '-u', '139'])

tm_scores = []

for line in str(ret).split('\\n'):
    if re.match(r'^TM-score=', line):
        score = line.split()[1:2] # Extract the value
        tm_scores.extend(score) # Saving only values

 # tm_scores now contains: ['0.94726', '0.96044', '0.96044']
```

While it being somewhat elaborate, it is a flexible and tunable solution. Note, if it will be used among other code, it would be better to wrap this into a function.

Answer (score 0):

My function wasn't that smart,I will let ouput write in to a file to do the follow

```
import os
cmd = './TMalign 3w4u.pdb 6bb5.pdb -u 139'
os.system(cmd + ">> 1.txt")
```